# Question closed for wrong reason, seems like it needs to be migrated?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, closed-questions

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199017/how-to-artificially-cause-a-page-fault-in-linux-kernel Was closed as unclear (which it was, but the comments fixed that), but it is realy off topic as it is a programing question. I flagged it for migration but that has not happened. Should I try to do anything about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's best to flag questions for the mods in this case if you notice they aren't being routed properly, or are stalled out, such is the case with this one. You can also alert other users of the site in the chatroom to enlist their assistance if you're unsure what to do.

As to this particular question, I've merged the comments into the question, so that it more clearly states what the OP is actually trying to accomplish. I'll migrate the question to SO.